# Weka PCA in Java class

Tags: java, weka, pca

I have a table where each row contains a record. The first element (first column) of each record is the object and the remaining fields denote certain attribute of the object. Its a`m x n` matrix. I want to calculate first principal comoponent of this matrix by implementing weka `PCA` in my java project. Please some one tell me:

1. how can I import weka PCA method in my java code and
2. get the first principal component

Comment: Write a program to do it for you, and if you run into a specific problem post the code here and we can help you.

Comment: That's the spirit Kviiri

Comment: I have already created the covariance matrix in my code. Now, I need to pass it to the PCA method of Weka. But I am not sure about the corresponding method and its implementation. I tried to search weka documentation to find the necessary methods and its signature. But unfortunately, I failed to do so.

Answer (score -1):

You first have to transform your matrix in Weka's dataformat using instances (basically instances are rows, and attributes are columns). Should be easy to do so, I think Weka eventually has methods to do so (build an `Instances` object from an double matrix)

Then you can compute the PCA as follows:

```
PrincipalComponents pca = new PrincipalComponents();
pca.buildEvaluator(dataSet);
```

With

```
pca.getEigenValues()
pca.getUnsortedEigenVectors()
```

you revieve the information about the prinicpal components. You also can print an summary using

```
pca.principalComponentsSummary()
```

which prints a nice summary, including the components (to a given degree, `setMaximumAttributeNames` specifies how many attributes are **printed** in this summary